# Some commands are not working in vim

Tags: vim

I am new to Vim. I'm following [these](http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/vim-novice-tutorial-videos/#Welcome) tutorials to help me learn to use it.

But some of my commands are not working, for example:

```
Capital W.
f followed by a character. (To move to next same char.)
```

Why is this happening and how can I get these commands to work?

Comment: It should work if you are in command mode.

Comment: The commands `W` and `fx` don't work? What does happen when you try them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

this may be because by default Ubuntu has a cut down version of vim called `vim-tiny` and many commands don't work in `vim-tiny`. To get full functionality you need to install `vim`. You can install `vim` with following command

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Try these commands after installing vim and let me know if you still have problems.

Answer (score 3):

Usually VIM runs in VI compatibility mode by default.

Try switching modes and see if the commands work. Use this to see which mode you are in:

```
:set compatible?
```

Then

```
:set compatible
```

or

```
:set nocompatible
```

to switch to the other mode and give your commands a try.

Adding

```
set nocompatible
```

or

```
set compatible
```

to a file called ".vimrc" in your home directory will make the setting the default for vim.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of capital `W`. I dont know what it is supposed to do, it works just like small `w`, moving to the next word.

Regarding `f` followed by a character will move to the character only in the current line. If you want to move to a character else where use `/` and the character and press enter. `?` for reverse. 
I too got confused with `f` first.

Comment: `w` moves to the next word, `W` moves to the next WORD. A WORD is basically anything delimited by white space.